# What's the output of ICs if only one source pin is connected ( Vcc or ground)

Tags: digital-logic

Let's suppose I have an AND gate whose output is connected to an OR gate. The OR gate is powered normally but the AND gate is only connected to +5 volt and the ground is disconnected (or viceversa) . What is the input of the OR gate? Is it undetermined? It's in a hogh impedance state? Does it depend on the state of the AND inputs?

Answer (score 2):

This depends on *implementation detail* but in general it is a *prohibited condition*.

Modern CMOS-based technologies are extremely fragile and easily damaged by electrostatic discharge.  To attempt to protect the internals against this, I/O pins are traditionally protected against over/under voltage by diodes shunting out of range inputs to the supply rails.

But the diodes are not sized for continuous usage, hence application of a voltage more than a diode drop outside of the supply range to an I/O pin is typically prohibited; when the supply rail is unpowered that become a prohibition of having any I/O above a half volt or so.  Exceptions would be where it is explicitly allowed (eg some kinds of "5v tolerant pins"), or allowed up to some limit of *injection current* (for example pins that the manufacturer *explicitly says* can be "5v tolerant" with a suitable series resistor).

In addition to being a specification violation, attempting to apply a voltage without a supply will typically result in the chip trying to run off the I/O voltage, through the protection diode, and even backpowering the supply net on the board.  This tends to load the signal beyond the point of meaning, and may also put the chip or board in an indeterminate state from which normal power-on reset may not work.

The short version:  **don't do that**.

Comment: I don't understand the risk because if Vcc is not connected, the whole chip is on GND or Z state. When GND is not connected current won't even attempt to cross the chip. Even if all the current from Vcc attempt to cross through the input of the next IC, it can't damage the latter.

Comment: @Fredled that would be a fundamental misunderstanding of the situation.  Physics doesn't care what is a "supply pin" vs what is an "input" - physics only cares about the structures behind.  We try to make inputs and supply pins distinct, but what we do to protect inputs against electrostatic discharges has the undesired effect that if the actual supply is missing, and input will unfortunately try to step up to its job.  That usually doesn't go well, and sometimes it damages the tiny little diode the current ends up flowing through, which wasn't meant for continuous current.

Comment: yet, I agree it's a prohibited condition. in the sens that you will see unexpected effects. It's just that I expect modern IC's to have been designed to resist to such situations. I can't imagine an IC which would be damaged just because it's Vcc or GND pin was accidentaly disconected. But I never made the test...

Comment: Often you'll get away with it for a while, but as with most out of spec conditions, you get away with it until you don't.  Work in this field long enough, and it's a question of when, not if.  Work with a wider variety of parts, and you'll find things that don't power-on-reset and boot up properly if they were previously "a tiny bit powered" via I/O current injection... even if they're seemingly fine once you remove the injection current or explicitly reset them.  You can also find power leached out of your "low power" design if you shut things down while leaving I/O's high.

Comment: If you mean ESD then I agree, the chip loses its protection significantly because the circuit is not complete. Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: The issue is not ESD, the issue is the path provided by the diodes put in to divert ESD, responding not to a brief ESD, but to the out-of-spec condition of having an I/O pin more than a diode drop above a supply pin.

Comment: OK, I understand.